# Teradata Procedure Locks a Log Table

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I am trying to get around a problem where the following SP locks the log table `DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE` and the lock is released only when the `DELETE ALL` and `INSERT-SELECT` statements are executed. This procedure chokes the whole ETL process. Moreover, this procedure is called via IBM Data Stage Sequence.

**Below is the procedure code:**

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DWH.HIST_PROC (OUT RETURN_MSG VARCHAR(100))
 
BEGIN
/**********************************
* DECALRE VARIABLES   *
**********************************/
DECLARE PJ_RID INTEGER;
DECLARE MS_Name VARCHAR(100); 
DECLARE JS_Name VARCHAR(100); 
DECLARE JT_Name VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE PJ_Domain VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE JS_Timestamp TIMESTAMP(0);
DECLARE Script_Name VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE Procedure_Name VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE JS_No INTEGER;
DECLARE SS_Ts TIMESTAMP(0);
DECLARE SR_Processed INTEGER;

/***********************************
* EXCEPTION HANDLING *
***********************************/
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN 
UPDATE DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE
SET 
JOB_STATUS = SQLCODE,
STEP_END_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
JOB_END_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)
WHERE JOB_RUN_ID = PJ_RID
AND STEP_NO = JS_No
AND JOB_NAME = JS_Name;

END;    

/**********************************
* SET VARIABLES            *
**********************************/
SET MS_Name = 'A Value';
SET JS_Name='A Value';
SET JT_Name = 'A Value';
SET PJ_Domain  = 'A Value';
SET JS_Timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0);
SET Script_Name = 'A Value';
SET Procedure_Name  = 'A Value';
SET SS_Ts   = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0);
SET JS_No   = 0;
SET RETURN_MSG  = 'Failure';

--------------------------------------------------------

--Insert log for step 0
INSERT INTO DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE
(
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.JOB_RUN_ID,                   
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.STEP_NO,                     
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.MASTER_SEQ_NAME ,              
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.JOB_NAME  ,                  
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.TABLE_NAME,                    
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.JS_Timestamp   ,        
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.JOB_END_TIMESTAMP          ,   
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.SS_Ts                 ,
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.STEP_END_TS                   ,
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.JOB_STATUS                    ,
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.JOB_DOMAIN                    ,
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.SCRIPT_NAME                  , 
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.PROCEDURE_NAME       ,         
DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE.RECORDS_PROCESSED             
)
VALUES
(:PJ_RID, :JS_No, :MS_Name, :JS_Name, :JT_Name,
:JS_Timestamp, NULL, :SS_Ts, NULL, NULL, :PJ_Domain, :Script_Name, :Procedure_Name, NULL
);

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS
SEL COALESCE(MAX(JOB_RUN_ID),0) + 1
FROM DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE
WHERE JOB_NAME = :JS_Name
AND Job_Domain = :PJ_Domain
INTO :PJ_RID;


/**********************************  DELETE/INSERT RTD_DATA *************************************************/
--Insert log for step 1
SET JS_No = JS_No + 1 ;
SET JT_Name = 'DWH.HISTORY_TABLE ';
SET SS_Ts = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0);
INSERT INTO DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE
VALUES(    :PJ_RID,    :JS_No,    :MS_Name,    :JS_Name,    :JT_Name,    :JS_Timestamp,
                        NULL,    :SS_Ts,    NULL,    NULL,    :PJ_Domain,    :Script_Name,    :Procedure_Name,    NULL);

DELETE FROM DWH.HISTORY_TABLE ALL;
INSERT INTO DWH.HISTORY_TABLE
( 
COLUMNLIST       
)
SELECT 
SI.COLUMNS,
S2.COLUMNS,
.
.
.
    
FROM SOMETABLE1 S1
INNER JOIN SOMETABLE2 S2
ON S1.ID = S2.ID
.
.
.
.;


--Update log for step 1
SET SR_Processed = ACTIVITY_COUNT;

UPDATE DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE
SET 
JOB_STATUS = SQLCODE,
STEP_END_TS = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
JOB_END_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),
RECORDS_PROCESSED = :SR_Processed
WHERE JOB_RUN_ID = PJ_RID
AND STEP_NO = JS_No
AND JOB_DOMAIN = PJ_Domain
AND PROCEDURE_NAME = Procedure_Name
AND "TABLE_NAME"=JT_Name;   

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET RETURN_MSG = 'Success' ;



END;
```

Based on same logic, many other stored procedures are executing on daily basis without any such issue. I am unable to understand, why this procedure locks the log table although both of its' insert statements have been executed.

I have tried to execute the individual DML statements in `BT` and `ET`, and doing such did not have any impact and the issue persisted. Moreover, I have optimized the underlying INSERT-SELECT. It has reduced the exeution time significantly but the locking is still occurring.

Anyone please, help me pinpoint why this issue is ocurring.

**EDIT:** Structure of log table.

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DWH_METADATA.LOG_TABLE ,FALLBACK ,
         NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
         NO AFTER JOURNAL,
         CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
         DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
         MAP = TD_MAP1
         (
          JOB_RUN_ID INTEGER,
          STEP_NO INTEGER,
          MASTER_SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          JOB_NAME VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          JOB_START_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6),
          JOB_END_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6),
          STEP_START_TS TIMESTAMP(0),
          STEP_END_TS TIMESTAMP(0),
          JOB_STATUS INTEGER,
          JOB_DOMAIN VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          SCRIPT_NAME VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          PROCEDURE_NAME VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          RECORDS_PROCESSED DECIMAL(18,0))
    PRIMARY INDEX ( JOB_NAME ,TABLE_NAME ,JOB_START_TIMESTAMP );
```

Comment: What is the Primary Index of the log table? Have you checked the query log to see whether DataStage wraps the CALL in BT/ET?

Comment: Finally, a response. I have added the DDL of log table. And the call is not in BT/ET in DataStage.

Comment: So the UPDATE (both at the end and within the condition handler block) will require a table-level write lock since not all Primary Index columns are specified with equality conditions in the WHERE clause. Let me rephrase my other question: Is this running in Teradata mode or ANSI mode and is auto-commit in effect? If you look at the query log (DBQL) for the log table inserts, what are the TxnMode and TxnUniq values?

Comment: Transaction mode is BTET. I guess, it can be assumed that the auto-commit is in effect.

Comment: True, default database behavior for BTET mode is to commit each request. But a driver can insert BT/ET "under the covers" to inhibit that automatic commit. Conversely for ANSI mode a driver might insert explicit COMMIT after every request so that it appears to the application that commits are "automatic".

Comment: I tried that as well. It did not work. I am planning to create a global temporary table for logging current days' run logs. And once everything is executed successfully I'll insert current runs' logs into the main table. Do you have any other suggestions please do let me know